# Is PHP synchronized or asynchronized?

Tags: php, asynchronous, synchronous

Consider:

```
<?php
    $list_years = getYears();
    require_once 'view.php';
?>
```

Here, getYears() is in another file. It's fetching a query. I'm using **$list_years** in file *view.php*.

Is it synchronized or asynchronized here?

Comment: I suspect you mean *synchronous*, and there is no way to tell because we don't know what getYears does.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What were the symptoms? What was expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code is procedural, so `getYears()` is executed always before  `require_once 'view.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 executes first, and it won’t find any function. You will need to include the file first.

You will get a fatal error:

> Call to undefined function getYears() in
> D:\wamp\www\synctest\index.php on line 2